# Animate custom slideshow opposite direction

Tags: jquery

I have a functional down arrow to browse a photo gallery. How would I configure the up arrow to navigate the opposite direction (up)?

I have written JQuery to add vertical scrolling functionality that displays only one photo per view (section) of the page.  when you select the down arrow, the next image in the photo gallery pops up.  I can't seem to configure the up arrow, unfortunately.  Any ideas on how I might be able to do this?

I have already tried configuring with the opposite operators ( - instead of + ) to navigate my href back (see below), but it doesn't work out as intended:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var currNum = 0;

  $('.down').click(function() {
    currNum += 1;
    var nextNum = currNum + 1;
    var nextLink = '#0' + nextNum.toString();
    $(this).attr('href', nextLink);

    $('.up').click(function() {
      var prevNum = currNum - 1;
      var prevLink = '#0' + prevNum.toString();
      $(this).attr('href', prevLink);
    });
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  var currNum = 0;

  $('.down').click(function() {
    currNum += 1;
    var nextNum = currNum + 1;
    var nextLink = '#0' + nextNum.toString();
    $(this).attr('href', nextLink);
  });
});
```

```html
<!--Container-->
<div id="container">

  <div id="cow"><img src="./img/cow.png" alt="icon!"></div>

  <div id="arrows">
    <a id="01" class="up" href="#01"><i class="down_icon"></i></a>
    <a id="01" class="down" href="#01"><i class="down_icon"></i></a>
  </div>

  <!--Images-->
  <div id="01" class="section"><img src="photo01.jpg" alt=""></div>
  <div id="02" class="section"><img src="photo02.jpg" alt=""></div>
  <div id="03" class="section"><img src="photo03.jpg" alt=""></div>

</div>
```

Comment: why DOM ready twice and a similar code inside?

Comment: why you use duplicate IDs? `id="01"` etc?

Comment: why `down_icon` twice?

Answer (score 0):

- By using IDs you're just restricting yourself from using **multiple galleries** on the same page.  **Use classes instead**.
- Create a wrapper for your items called `.Gallery-slider` (will be the transitioning element)
- Use `transform` and `transition` in CSS to animate!
- Use a `c` variable as counter, increment / decrement depending on the clicked button
- and use this tiny code to fix the counter (indexer) loop: `c = c<0 ? tot-1 : c%tot;`  (where `tot` is the total number of items)
- Translate Y the slider DIV by `-c * 100%`

```js
jQuery($ => { // DOM ready and $ alias in scope

  /**
   * Gallery component
   */

  $('.Gallery').each((i, el) => {
    
    let c = 0; // Start index Counter
    const $Slider = $(el).find('.Gallery-slider');
    const $UpDown = $(el).find('.up, .down');
    const tot = $Slider.children().length;    
    const animate = () => {
      c = c<0 ? tot-1 : c%tot; 
      $Slider.css({transform: `translateY(${-c * 100}%)`});
    };
    
    $UpDown.on('click', evt => {
      evt.preventDefault();
      c = $(evt.currentTarget).is('.down') ? ++c : --c;
      animate();
    });
    
  });
  
});
```

```css
* {box-sizing:border-box; margin:0;}

/**
 * Gallery component
 */
 
.Gallery {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 50vh;
}

.Gallery-slider {
  position: relative;
  height: inherit;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.Gallery-item {
  height: 100%;
}

.Gallery-item img {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.Gallery-arrows {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}

.Gallery-arrows a {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  font-size: 3em;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
}
.Gallery-arrows a.down {
 bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="Gallery">
  <div class="Gallery-slider">
    <div class="Gallery-item"><img src="//placehold.it/600x400/0bf?text=1" alt="1"></div>
    <div class="Gallery-item"><img src="//placehold.it/600x400/f0b?text=2" alt="2"></div>
    <div class="Gallery-item"><img src="//placehold.it/600x400/b0f?text=3" alt="3"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="Gallery-arrows">
    <a class="up"><i class="down_icon">&uarr;</i></a>
    <a class="down"><i class="up_icon">&darr;</i></a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="Gallery">
  <div class="Gallery-slider">
    <div class="Gallery-item"><img src="//placehold.it/600x400/ff0?text=As+many" alt="1"></div>
    <div class="Gallery-item"><img src="//placehold.it/600x400/00f?text=galleries+as" alt="2"></div>
    <div class="Gallery-item"><img src="//placehold.it/600x400/f00?text=you+need" alt="3"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="Gallery-arrows">
    <a class="up"><i class="down_icon">&uarr;</i></a>
    <a class="down"><i class="up_icon">&darr;</i></a>
  </div>
</div>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you, Roko!  It worked.  I know the code was a little scrappy, but I was trying to do it completely on my own without referencing how others have done it.  I'm a beginner...(if you didn't notice) :)